# Javascript google geolocation is not working in live site

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Google geolocation with Javascript is not working in live site for major browsers like Firefox, Chrome. Geolocation result is displaying in Opera for live site, where as the same is working in localhost for all browsers (Chrome, firefox & Opera). My Live site protocol using https://. See below code and suggest any..
    
    
    
    
    Geolocation and Google Maps API

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE&sensor=true"></script>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script>

function writeAddressName(latLng) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
"location": latLng
},
function(results, status) {
for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

//there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_2") {
//this is the object you are looking for
city= results[0].address_components[i];
break;
}
}
}
//alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name);
//alert(city.long_name);
var cityname = city.long_name;
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
document.getElementById("citynm").innerHTML = cityname;  }
else {
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Unable to retrieve your address" + "<br>"; }
});
}
function geolocationSuccess(position) {
var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
// Write the formatted address
writeAddressName(userLatLng);

var myOptions = {
zoom : 16,
center : userLatLng,
mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
// Draw the map
var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
// Place the marker
new google.maps.Marker({
map: mapObject,
position: userLatLng
});
// Draw a circle around the user position to have an idea of the current localization accuracy
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
center: userLatLng,
radius: position.coords.accuracy,
map: mapObject,
fillColor: '#0000FF',
fillOpacity: 0.5,
strokeColor: '#0000FF',
strokeOpacity: 1.0
});
mapObject.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
}

function geolocationError(positionError) {
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Error: " + positionError.message + "<br>";
}

function geolocateUser() {
// If the browser supports the Geolocation API
if (navigator.geolocation)
{
var positionOptions = {
enableHighAccuracy: true,
timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, positionOptions);
}
else
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API";
}
window.onload = geolocateUser;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="citynm"></p>
<p id="address"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it working in any of single browser like chrome or other

Answer (score 1):

I have tested you codes (Chrome v29, Windows 8), the one below works from a remote server (non-local host) but you need note note 2 areas

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&sensor=true"></script>
```

I added v=3.9

And

```
function writeAddressName(latLng) {
    ...
    if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "route") {
```

You may need to handle case where **city** cannot be set.

I can see the address. [This sample does not include map display]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&sensor=true"></script>
<script>
function writeAddressName(latLng) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ "location": latLng }, function(results, status) {
        for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {
                //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "route") {
                //this is the object you are looking for
                    city = results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
//alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name);
//alert(city.long_name);
        var cityname = city.long_name;
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
            document.getElementById("citynm").innerHTML = cityname;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Unable to retrieve your address" + "<br>";
        }
    });
}

function geolocationSuccess(position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
// Write the formatted address
    writeAddressName(userLatLng);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom : 16,
        center : userLatLng,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    // Draw the map
    var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    // Place the marker
    new google.maps.Marker({
        map: mapObject,
        position: userLatLng
    });
// Draw a circle around the user position to have an idea of the current localization accuracy
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: userLatLng,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy,
        map: mapObject,
        fillColor: '#0000FF',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeColor: '#0000FF',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0
    });
    mapObject.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
}

function geolocationError(positionError) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Error: " + positionError.message + "<br>";
}

function geolocateUser() {
    // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var positionOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, positionOptions);
    }
    else
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API";
}
window.onload = geolocateUser;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="error"></p>
<p id="citynm"></p>
<p id="address"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ..Thanks for your effort still I am not getting alert message here in firefox
var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
alert(userLatLng); // alert with coordinate points are not dispalying.

Anyway as per the requirement, here I am using ajax and redirecting geo points to another page. I have just one last issue...  Geo point alerts appearing in chrome and opera.. but not working in firefox. Strangely, few times those alert popups in firefox also appeared, now it is not at all working.. Plz suggest to work in firefox also

Comment: could you try console.log(google, position); before calling the google.maps.LatLng(...) to see if google and position objects is ok? use firebug on firefox to check the console output instead of using alert, you get more info

Comment: Yeah.. I checked it in console Error: Blocked loading mixed active content "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key= ...  & Blocked loading mixed active content "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&sensor=true"

Comment: maybe your page is https and you calling using http. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire

Comment: I changed to https:// now above two erros are not coming.. Another error "TypeError: cd is not a function" in main.js (line 47) file. Path showing "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/12/17/main.js"

Comment: I got that error too earlier on, what I did was just comment out all the javascript and slowly put them on 1 by 1, it may (just guess) have something to do with function writeAddressName(latLng) {
    ...
    if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "route") {, the hardcoded string

Answer (score 0):

May be this links can help you

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

[google maps api works at localhost but doesn't work at web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603936/google-maps-api-works-at-localhost-but-doesnt-work-at-web-server)

Comment: @Sourav... your answered 2nd link is useful. I am not getting alert message at this below point 
var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
alert(userLatLng); // alert with coordinate points are not dispalying.

Anyway as per the requirement, here I am using ajax and redirecting geo points to another page. I have just one last issue...  Geo point alerts appearing in chrome and opera.. but not working in firefox. Strangely, few times those alert popups in firefox also appeared, now it is not at all working.. Plz suggest to work in firefox also

Answer (score 0):

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en&csw=1#browsersupport



https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

http://jsfiddle.net/BQzLq/3/

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/21849?hl=en

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

These all links is just for your knowledge in some browser or browser's older versions google map v3 doesn't works.
```

Comment: ..Thanks for your effort still I am not getting alert message here in firefox var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude); alert(userLatLng); // alert with coordinate points are not dispalying. Anyway as per the requirement, here I am using ajax and redirecting geo points to another page. I have just one last issue... Geo point alerts appearing in chrome and opera.. but not working in firefox. Strangely, few times those alert popups in firefox also appeared, now it is not at all working.. Plz suggest to work in firefox also